# projections in a diffuse von Neumann algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a diffuse von Neumann algebra and $\varphi$ be a faithful normal state on $M$.

If $s,t$ are two positive elements in $M$ such that $\varphi(s)=\lambda \varphi(t)$, where $\lambda$ is the point spectrum of $\varphi$. Then we can find $\epsilon>0$ and two non-zero projections $p,q\in M$ such that $\epsilon p\leq s,\epsilon q\leq t$ and $\varphi(p)=\lambda \varphi(q)$.

Since $M$ is diffuse, there is no minimal projections in $M$, there exist projection $p\leq I$, but how to assure that $\epsilon p\leq s I$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $s$ is not zero, there exists $\epsilon'>0$ such that $\sigma(a)\cap[\epsilon',\infty)\ne\varnothing$. Take $\epsilon''$ to be the same thing for $t$, and take any  $\epsilon>0$ with $\epsilon≤\min\{\epsilon',\epsilon''\}$. Let $$p'=\ 1_{[\epsilon,\infty)}(s),\qquad\qquad q'=\ 1_{[\epsilon,\infty)}(t).$$ Then $$\epsilon p'\leq s,\qquad\qquad \epsilon q'\leq t.$$ Because $M$ is diffuse and $\varphi$ is faithful and normal, there exist subprojections $p\leq p'$ with $\varphi(p)$ any number in $(0,\varphi(p')]$. Now choose numbers $a\in(0,\varphi(p')]$ and $b\in(0,\varphi(q')]$ with $a=\lambda b$. Then let $p\leq p'$ with $\varphi(p)=a$ and $q\leq q'$ with $\varphi(q)=b$.

Comment: Why can we take $\varphi(p)$ be  any number $\in(0,\varphi(p')]$. According to the definition, we only know that $p$ is not minimal.

Comment: And that $M$ is diffuse and that $\varphi$ is faithful and normal.

Comment: You mean we can use the intermediate value Theorem on $P'MP'$?

Comment: The only "intermediate value theorem" I know is the one in calculus, which wouldn't apply here. But it is trivial to check that since $M$ is diffuse $\varphi(a)$ for $q$ a projection has to take any value in between

Comment: Given a projection $p$, we know that there exists a projection $p'$ such that $\varphi(p')\leq \varphi(p)$. But to check that the following conclusion: for any $\delta\in (0,\varphi(p)),$  there exists a projection $e\leq p$ such that $\varphi(e)=\delta$?

Comment: Suppose that $q\leq p$ a proper subprojection. Since $M$ is diffuse, there exists a proper subprojection $r\leq p-q$. Then $\varphi(r)<\varphi(p)-\varphi(q)$. So $q+r$ is a subprojection of $p$ with $$\varphi(q)<\varphi(q+r)<\varphi(p).$$ This shows that there cannot be gaps in the values.